# NodeJS thinks I am duplicating parameter names when I am not

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Thanks for looking at my question.

In this javascript initialization code, on line 94, I am getting a syntax error: "Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context".  However, I am not duplicating any parameters.  All of my functions' parameters names are unique within their scope.

The repository is at https://github.com/allenchan3/foodproject/blob/c3442a3b8542e1f9cbcc5f3f78175765a292dd9a, and the script in question is at https://github.com/allenchan3/foodproject/blob/c3442a3b8542e1f9cbcc5f3f78175765a292dd9a/server/config/initialize.js.  The error is appearing on the function call to `create_menu_items`. I carefully inspected this file for duplicate parameter names but found none.  I tried changing the names of each of the 3 declared variables in the main function, along with changing the names of the parameters.  Nothing seems to get rid of the syntax error, which is preventing my function from executing.

```
async function create_menu_items(filenames, directory, cat_names_to_ids) {
    /// stuff
}
async function main() {
    await create_menu_items(menu_item_filenames, menu_item_dir, categories_name_to_id);
}


[skyler@laptop server]$ npm start
[.....snip.....]
(node:6571) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context
```

As mentioned, this error keeps appearing and the function `create_menu_items` doesn't run, even though I think it should, because none of the parameters appear to be in conflict with anything.

Thanks again for taking a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/allenchan3/foodproject/blob/c3442a3b8542e1f9cbcc5f3f78175765a292dd9a/server/config/initialize.js#L51) your problem

```
objects.reduce((prev_items,curr_items_obj,_,_)=>{
                                          ^ ^
```

It seems that you wanted to omit optional parameters this way, but you should just skip them like this:

```
objects.reduce((prev_items,curr_items_obj)=>{
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really care to use `_` for omited parameters, name the other one as `__` (double underscore) to avoid duplicate parameter error, as such:

```
objects.reduce((prev_items,curr_items_obj,_,__)=>{
```